# Moving BizTalk 2006 Database from SQL 2000 to SQL 2005

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2006

Has anybody had any experience migrating a BizTalk 2006 server from a SQL 2000 server to a SQL 2005 Server?  I understand that nothing changes as far as the content of the databases - views, stored procs, etc. all remain the same.  The scheduled jobs have to be migrated.  All of that aside... tips, trick, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd start with "[Moving BizTalk Server Databases](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa559835.aspx)" in the BizTalk documentation